# SQL Server Error 223 When Connecting

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

I recently changed SQL Server 2008 from windows authentication mode, to mixed. I created a new user 'taraw' and set a password. I'm connecting to localhost - which works perfect when using windows authentication, however if I want to use SQL Server authentication with my user - taraw, I get the following error:

> Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No
>   process is on the other end of the
>    pipe (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 233)pipe (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 233)

I know the password is correct as I've just created it, I've also tried creating different users, to which I get the same result. I've read somewhere that Namespipes might be disabled? But I haven't found out where or even how to enable this. (EDIT: I have since found this, and it is enabled)

If anyone has any advice it would be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have since solved this problem. I was previously restarting the server within SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO, this was incorrect.

I simply restarted the SQL Server within SQL Server Configuration Manager and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. Control Panel > Administrative tools > Services > Right click > Run as Administrator > SQL Server (SQL Express) > Right click > Stop and Start resolved the issue for me. :)