# How can I resolve error 233 in SQL Server 2005 under Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-7

I'm creating a new login with SQL Server authentication. Once the login is created, I then try to connect to the database using SQL Server authentication. This produces the following error:

> Cannot connect to (SERVER NAME) i.e machine name/sql\express

Additional Information:

> A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then
>   an error  occurred during the login
>   process.  (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider,  error: 0 - No process is on
>   the other end of the pipe.) 
>   (Microsoft SQL  Server, Error: 223)

Here is what I have already tried for troubleshooting:

- Enabling all the protocols
- Ensuring that I am running as Administrator
- Setting the Authentication Mode to Windows and SQL Server Authentication

Unfortunately, none of these steps seem to have worked. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does the actual message contain "machine name/sql\express"?

Comment: Hi gbn Actually it is message like"cannot connect to server saswati-pc\sqlexpress" and meg description as above.....

Comment: Probably nor programming related. Either firewall or antivirus is blocking connection: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/036fbb34-faa5-43a9-ba43-e229693dcd6b/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post that not only contains screen shots on how to enable\disable a login, it gives you some more info on SQL security (incase somebody googles this answer and needs the info)

http://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Log in to Sql Server via a `Windows` account and then expand `Security` and then `Logins`.  If you see that `sa` or your new account has a downward facing arrow in the bottom right hand corner of the icon, right mouse click the `login` and select `Properties`.  In here, click `Status` on the left hand side and then check the `Enabled` radio button and then click `OK`.  Then, try and log in with this account.

Comment: Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager` and check that the `SQL Express` service has started.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to restart SQL Server as a SERVICE!!!

You can do it with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
This answer was OK on similar question
[SQL Server Error 223 When Connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022676/sql-server-error-223-when-connecting)